# What does decltype((...)) with double parentheses mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-inference, decltype

I don't understand the last line of the example on page 148 of the FCD (§7.6.1.2/4):

```
const int&& foo();
int i;
struct A { double x; };
const A* a = new A();
decltype(foo()) x1 = i;     // type is const int&&
decltype(i) x2;             // type is int
decltype(a->x) x3;          // type is double
decltype((a->x)) x4 = x3;   // type is const double&
```

Why do the parentheses make a difference here? Shouldn't it simply be `double` like in the line above?

Comment: Backreferenced: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/01/22/expression-list-in-functional-cast/

Comment: @JanSchultke The dupe doesn't really explain this case. It fails to specify when `decltype` returns `T &&` on expressions, and doesn't explicitly mention double parentheses, which is far from obvious.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm working on an edit or new answer that goes more into detail for double parentheses. In any case, it's not necessary for an answer to exist for something to be a dupe target.

Comment: @JanSchultke *"working on an edit or new answer"* That's good. *"not necessary for an answer"* Formally yes, but then closing isn't very helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Just above that example, it says

> - if e is an unparenthesized id-expression or a class member access (5.2.5), decltype(e) is the type of the entity named by e.
> - if e is an lvalue, decltype(e) is T&, where T is the type of e;

I think `decltype(a->x)` is an example of the "class member access" and `decltype((a->x))` is an example of lvalue.

Comment: But that does not explain the const :)

Comment: @FredOverflow: Does too: `a` has type `const A*`

Comment: "class member access" should be "class data member access"

Answer (score 20):

```
decltype(a->x)
```

This gives you the type of the member variable `A::x`, which is `double`.

```
decltype((a->x))
```

This gives you the type of the expression `(a->x)`, which is an lvalue expression (hence why it is a const reference--`a` is a `const A*`).

Comment: Okay, I understand how the rules can be applied here now, but *why* are the rules like that? Why does it make sense to distinguish between `a->x` and `(a->x)`? It seems so random to me. Why would I ever want that behavior? Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, but both `decltype(f())` and `decltype ((f()))` yield `int` on my system. Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: @Fred:  Nevermind.  I was wrong.  In that particular case, the parentheses are ignored, so both should be `const int`.

Answer (score 11):

The added parens are turning it into a lvalue.

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537655.aspx)
The inner parentheses cause the statement to be evaluated as an expression instead of a member access. And because a  is declared as a const pointer, the type is a reference to const double.