# Do decltype(c) e; and decltype((c)) f; declare different types?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [decltype and parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097779/decltype-and-parenthesis)

I found this on wikipedia :

```
    auto c = 0;           // c has type int
    auto d = c;           // d has type int
    decltype(c) e;        // e has type int, the type of the entity named by c
    decltype((c)) f = c;  // f has type int&, because (c) is an lvalue
```

And using ideone compiler (C++0x idk what they use) and typeinfo I was unable to see diff between e and f. Obviously it is probably fail on my part, so I would like to know if this is final C++11 standard behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and this is the standard behavior. It is written in §7.1.6.2[dcl.type.simple]/4, where:

> The type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
>
> - if `e` is an **unparenthesized *id-expression*** or an unparenthesized class member access, `decltype(e)`
>     is the type of the entity named by e.
> - ...
> - otherwise, if `e` is an lvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;
> - ...

Since `c` does not have parenthesis and is an *id-expression* (here, an identifier, see §5.1.1[expr.prim.general]/7), `decltype(c)` will be the type of `c`, which is `int`.

Since `(c)` do have parenthesis and is an lvalue (e.g. `(c)=1` is a valid expression), `decltype((c))` will be the lvalue reference type of type of `(c)`, which is `int&`.

Comment: good to know, btw any other part of C++  for which (SOMETHING) has one semantic and ((SOMETHING)) diff semantic meaning.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: `1-2*3` vs `(1-2)*3`, `int*x[10]` vs `int(*x)[10]`, ... ?

Comment: you didnt understand me.... (1-2)*3 is the same as ((1-2))*3

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Macro's. `FOO(x,y)` passes two parameters x and y, `FOO((X,Y))` passes one parameter `(X,Y)`.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Off-topic but anyway, when `x` is an integer, `int f(int(x));` declares a function `f(int)`, and `int f((int(x)));` declares an integer `f=x` ([most vexing parse](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1424510/509868))