# Why is decltype defining a variable as a reference?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was studying about the differences between `auto` and `decltype` type specifier and I saw in another question that when I use `decltype` with a reference, like this:

```
const int ci = 0, &cj = ci;
decltype(ci) x = 0;
decltype(cj) y = x;
```

`decltype(cj)` will not give me the type of the object that `cj` refers to (that is, `const int`) but will give me the type of `cj` itself. So `y` will be `const int&`.

Why does this happen? And it could affect my code in someway? Is it related to the difference between `decltype()` and `decltype(())`?

Comment: `decltype` gives you the *declared type* of the object, which in this case is `const int&`.

Comment: It happens because that's what `decltype` was designed to do. We already have `auto` to ignore the reference.

Comment: @chris so basically, decltype should be used to deal with references and auto not?

Comment: I guess it should be noted that `decltype` has other uses like determining which type to use as a return type (which couldn't be left out in C++11), and there are times when you need to grab a type without a new variable. But as `decltype` vs. `auto` for declaring variables like this, that would be the main difference. Of course `decltype` also allows you to use a different initialization method instead of just copying. `decltype` really isn't something that's too common in user code, though. More generic library code.

Comment: @chris that was an awesome explanation and it helped me a lot in terms of understanding when/why to use decltype. Thank you for that! And when I ask about decltype() and decltype(()), is there something related with reference?

Comment: @GabrielMello, That's explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097779/decltype-and-parentheses).

Comment: @chris Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules of `decltype` are fairly straightforward (especially when compared to lots of other rules in C++...). For an expression `e`, `decltype(e)` is (from [dcl.type.simple], paraphrasing):

- if `e` is an unparenthesized *id-expression*, then the type of `e`. Exactly the type of `e`. We're not dropping *cv*-qualifiers or references or anything. `decltype(ci)` is `const int` because that is the type of `ci`. Likewise, `decltype(cj)` is `const int&`.
- If `e` is an xvalue, then `T&&` where `T` is the type of `e`.
- If `e` is an lvalue, then `T&` where `T` is the type of `e`.
- Else, the type of `e`.

We go in order through those bullet points. Where the parentheses makes a difference is when we do `decltype((ci))` - `(ci)` is not an unparenthesized *id-expression* anymore, so we don't simply take the type of `ci`. Instead, it's just an lvalue - so we take the type of the expression (`const int`) and add a reference to it. Hence, `decltype((ci))` is `const int&`. `decltype((cj))` is still `const int&`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me a lot and you had explained very well.

Answer (score 2):

*Why is it `double const&`?* Well, that is the type of the variable.

*Is it related to `decltype(())`?* Yes, no, not really, the rules for the two are subtly different, but should both be understood if you are planning on using them.

---

`decltype` and `auto` are very useful additions to C++, a sound understanding of their meaning and use is very useful especially if they are being used in the code. In client type code, `auto` will probably be much more common.

**What is `decltype()`?**

`decltype` offers a mechanism to get to the type given a variable or expression. It generally features in more generic code, most likely when templates are involved.

**What is `auto`?**

`auto` is effectively a way to say "I don't care for the name of the type (it may be too long), but I want a variable of that type", for e.g. the indexer in a `for` loop. Note; there are differences between `auto`, `auto&` and `auto&&`; they are well documented here on SO and elsewhere (such as cppreference.com).

Comment: Very organized explanation and I liked how you goes straight to the point. Thank you for that.