# Type of (x) in C++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, decltype

Given:

```
decltype(auto) f1()
{
    int x = 0;
    return x;  // decltype(x) is int, so f1 returns int
}
decltype(auto) f2()
{
    int x = 0;
    return (x);  // decltype((x)) is int&, so f2 returns int&
}
```

(Taken from Scott Meyer's Effective Modern C++).

Now, if I have found the correct paragraph, **Section 7.1.5.2 Simple type specifiers [dcl.type.simple]** of the C++ standard says:

> If e is an id-expression or a class member access (5.2.5 [expr.ref]),
>   decltype(e) is defined as the type of the entity named by e

and the example from that section is:

```
struct A { double x; }

const A* a = new A();

decltype((a->x)); // type is const double&
```

Now, I wonder why is the `decltype((x))` is deduced to be `int&` in the book.

Comment: why do you need the decltype for? auto is enough..

Comment: works fine without the decltype : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cb0832e241a967e

Comment: but let's face it, the answer will probably be someone quoting from standard some weird-ass neuance of some esoteric rule which makes it behave like it..

Comment: @DavidHaim added the tag for weird-ass nuances of esoteric rules.

Comment: Scott Mayer explained it - `(x)` is an expression, and expressions 'return' references (think `(x+=0)`)

Comment: What else could `decltype((x))` be? Did you expect anything else than `int&`? If yes, please specify what. It seems pretty obvious - the book and the Standard agree - so you might want to specify what exactly is surprising/unclear here.

Comment: @Quentin This is exactly what "Language Lawyer" stands for, LOL!

Comment: @anatolyg: In the same vein I could say that it seems pretty obvious he expected `int`. What else? You follow the rules of the standard, I follow the rules of basic human reasoning.

Comment: @DavidHaim While what you describe does happen frequently on this site, I would hardly call this quite non corner case use of a high profile C++11 feature a "weird-ass neuance of some esoteric rule".

Comment: See [decltype and parentheses](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3097779/1708801)

Comment: @BaummitAugen , well, I was sarcastic and vulgar, true, but I dought anyone will intentially write the mixture of `decltype(auto)` with `return (something)`, especially when `auto` + `return x` works good enough

Comment: @DavidHaim but `auto` + `return x;` returns a `int`, not a `int&`.

Comment: ... which is exactly what he expected to get..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20721887/576911 for a tool `expression_name` that is handy for exploring this issue.

Answer (score 10):

The relevant standards quote is:

> `N4140 [dcl.type.simple]/4:` For an expression `e`, the type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
>
> - if e is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access (5.2.5), `decltype(e)`
>   is the type of the entity named by `e`. If there is no such entity, or if e names a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;
> - otherwise, if `e` is an xvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&&`, where `T` is the type of e;
> - **otherwise, if `e` is an lvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type of e**;
> - otherwise, `decltype(e)` is the type of `e`.

Since `x` is an lvalue, and the expression is parenthesized, the third rule is used, so `decltype((x))` is `int&`.

Answer (score 8):

`decltype` returns the declared type of a variable, or the "type" of an expression (with some reference added to indicate l/r valueness).

This lets it be used for two different purposes.  Sometimes this causes confusion, but it is what it is.

The token `x` is a variable.  The type of the variable is `int`.

The tokens `(x)` are *not* a variable, but rather a (really trivial) expression containing nothing but one variable.  As such, the type of the *expression* (as determined by decltype) `(x)` is `int&`.

The type of the expression `x` (if you could convince decltype to give it to you; you cannot) is also `int&`, but the rule that the `decltype(ACTUAL_VAR_NAME)` evaluates to the type of the variable "wins".

Now, none of the above is true.  The actual truth is a quote of the standard which describes the steps that a compiler is supposed to go through to determine what type `decltype` returns.  But it is an effective lie, and one (if the standard wording turned out to have errors) that might indicate the standard has a bug when it disagrees with it.

Answer (score 5):

§ 7.1.6.4 [dcl.spec.auto] (draft n3797)

> 7. ... If the placeholder is the
>      decltype(auto)
>      type-specifier
>      , the declared type of the variable or return type
>      of the function shall be the placeholder alone. The type deduced for the variable or return type is determined
>      as described in
>      7.1.6.2
>      , as though the initializer had been the operand of the
>      decltype
>      .

§ 7.1.6.2 [dcl.type.simple]

> 4. For an expression
>      e
>      , the type denoted by
>      decltype(e)
>      is defined as follows:
>
> —
>    if
>   e
>   is an unparenthesized
>   id-expression
>   or an unparenthesized class member access (
>   5.2.5
>   ),
>   decltype(e)
>   is the type of the entity named by
>   e
>   . If there is no such entity, or if
>   e
>   names a set of overloaded func-
>   tions, the program is ill-formed;
>
> —
>    otherwise, if
>   e
>   is an xvalue,
>   decltype(e)
>   is
>   T&&
>   , where
>   T
>   is the type of
>   e
>   ;
>
> —
>    otherwise, if
>   e
>   is an lvalue,
>   decltype(e)
>   is
>   T&
>   , where
>   T
>   is the type of
>   e
>   ;
>
> —
>    otherwise,
>   decltype(e)
>   is the type of
>   e

`x` is is an unparenthesized id-expression and therefore the return type is deduced as the type of `x`: `int`

`(x)` is *not* an **un**parenthesized id-expression so that rule does not apply. However, it *is* a (parenthesized) lvalue expression. Therefore the deduced type is `T&` where `T` is the type of `x`: `int&`

Comment: @downvoter is there a mistake in the answer? How can I improve it?

Answer (score 5):

[dcl.spec.auto]/7 mandates  that, roughly speaking, the return type is obtained by applying `decltype` to the expression in the `return` statement. Thus, as the comment suggests, we're looking for `decltype((x))`. A fiendish rule steps in:

[image]

Note that the first bullet point does not apply since the expression *is* parenthesized. Hence we get `int&`.

---

This distinction between applications of `decltype` on plain identifiers and parenthesized ones was introduced with revision 6 of the corresponding paper. See in [revision 5](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1978.pdf), §2.3:

> The type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
>
> 1. If `e` is of the form `(e1)`, `decltype(e)` is defined as `decltype(e1)`.

The justification behind this is presumably the following: Writing `(x)`, the programmer intends `decltype` to not treat the operand as a name but rather an expression - considering its value category.

Answer (score 0):

As @Columbo has already pointed out, (a->x) is to be taken as an expression, and that expression **is** `const` qualified, because *a is const.

Let's consider this

```
decltype((a->x));
```

was not `const` qualified.

Then e.g. this

```
decltype((a->x)) ref = (a->x);
```

would implicitly sort-of lift the *a const qualifier, because *a's x would become mutable through `ref`.